# Custom List Adapter Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android

I have a custom list adapter create for an app, but I don't know how to implement it. Can somebody show me how? I am trying to get the id of a county and use that as it's item number within my list 1,2,3..., rather than 0,1,2,3.

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter<County>
{
    Activity context;
    public List<County> listCounty;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<County> lCounties)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listCounty = lCounties;
    }

    public override int Count {
        get { return this.listCounty.Count; }
    }

    public override County this [int position] {
        get { return this.listCounty[position]; }
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = this.listCounty[position];
        var view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null || !(convertView is LinearLayout))
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Main, parent, false);
        var textTop = view.FindViewById (Resource.Id.listView) as TextView;
        textTop.SetText (item.CountyName, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        return view;
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
}
```

And the class to go along with it

```
public class County
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In `GetItemId()`, try something similar to `return this.listCounty[position].ID;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet of a custom list adapter

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: So was I was not far of it so?

Comment: It is in JAVA, not C#